How to stop PNG compression on GeoTIFF files?
so i've recently started using R using Milos Agathon's 'How to Make Amazing 3D Vintage Topo Maps'. I've noticed I lose quite a lot of quality when converting my GeoTiff to PNG (timestamp 13:00), and it's affecting legibility of my maps.
PNG left, vs GeoTiff Right.

I'll attach my code below, I wanted to know how I can avoid this?
# 6. RESAMPLE OLD TOPO MAP

africa_topo_resampled <- terra::resample(
  x = africa_topo_tif,
  y = africa_dem_3857,
  method = "bilinear"
)

img_file <- "fourteen_minutes_twenty_seconds.png"

terra::writeRaster(
  africa_topo_resampled,
  img_file,
  overwrite = T,
  NAflag = 255
)

africa_topo_img <- png::readPNG(
  img_file
)


png is a lossless format. The issue is likely due to resample(), which 'moves' your geotiff to align with africa_dem_3857. Doing so results in distortions. Does the issue persist if your compare the result of terra::writeRaster(africa_topo_tif, img_file, overwrite = T, NAflag = 255) with africa_topo_tif? It would be easier to help you if you made your question a a minimal, reproducible example.
